# How to select an array properly in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I want to order a list of items by multiple properties. So I use an array that I bind in a variable.

Everything works fine until I let the user choose order options with a `select`. It breaks when my array has more than 1 value... and it seems to defaults to the `track by $index` order.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
 {a: "3", b: "First"},
 {a: "2", b: "Second"},
 {a: "1", b: "Third"}
    ];
    $scope.my_orderby = ['a','b'];
    $scope.my_selected = {
 a: ['a'],
 b: ['b'],
 ab: ['a','b'],
 ba: ['b','a']
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="my_orderby.push(my_orderby.shift())">In place: {{my_orderby}}</button>
  <select ng-model="my_orderby">
    <option value="{{v}}" ng-repeat="(k,v) in my_selected">{{k}}</option>
  </select>
  <button ng-click="items.push(items.shift())">{{items}}</button>
  <hr/>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:my_orderby track by $index">{{item.a}} {{item.b}}</div>
</div>
```

How am I supposed to do to allow sorting by multiple properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Poney** gave me the right lead for an answer.

`OPTION` converts my `array` to `CDATA object`. Not sure what a CData array looks like, but avoiding it solved my issue.

> https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION.

To preserve my array, I had to combine `ng-options` with `ng-change` and do the change in a javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working with ng-options. I guess that "value" is converting the value to a string instead of keeping it as an array.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
 {a: "3", b: "First"},
 {a: "2", b: "Second"},
 {a: "1", b: "Third"}
    ];
    $scope.my_orderby = ['a','b'];
    $scope.my_selected = {
 a: ['a'],
 b: ['b'],
 ab: ['a','b'],
 ba: ['b','a']
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="my_orderby.push(my_orderby.shift())">In place: {{my_orderby}}</button>
  <select ng-model="my_orderby" ng-options="item as index for (index, item) in my_selected">
  </select>
  <button ng-click="items.push(items.shift())">{{items}}</button>
  <hr/>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:my_orderby track by $index">{{item.a}} {{item.b}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted. Not 100% working but you gave me the right lead for a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it will help you. Thank you.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'a'">{{item.a}} {{item.b}}</div>
```

Comment: It does not help because I want it to work with an array... thanks anyway